# Collect codes for non-retail scenario

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, session, einstein-recommendations

Can we use collect codes for non-retail scenarios especially if I wanted to track unknown visitor activity on my website and tie back that activity when a user provides an email on a sign-up page? (I don't need any Einstein recommendations or Predictive intelligence in this case because we use GA360) 
 
 1. Track anonymous visitor activity using collect codes and store in a Data extension 
 2. **Without** a cloud page (from an external website), capture user details including email and post to a data extension (via. API) 
 3. Look for any activity captured in IGO_ and PI_ data extensions previously for the newly recorded email address and tie that activity for advanced segmentation requirements.
 
 
Also please shed some light where exactly I can find browser details, pageview details, etc. in IGO_ and PI_ data extensions.
 
 
Any help here is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
 
 
Chandu

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can indeed be done, however please observe [the prerequisites](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_personalization_builder_prerequisites.htm&type=5) for implementing this. You need a.o. to have a catalogue in place, for your content. Items not in catalogue will not be tracked and passed on to data extensions. Once prerequisites are in place, you will be able to [connect the data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_enable_pb_data_extensions.htm&type=5) from collect code to your PI/IGO Data Extensions. Please refer to the notification on the page where you enable the connection, for any outstanding configuration, before the connection can be made.

You can use the [DEManager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5) to push data into a Data Extension from an external website. This is far the simplest solution, as it doesn't require you to use any API integrations. An example can be seen here:

```
        <form action="http://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="12345" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="WebCollectSubs" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="http://example.com/Success" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="http://example.com/Failed" />
        Email: <input type="text" name="Email"><br />
        First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br />
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Replace the `_clientID` with the MID where you want the data. `_deExternalKey` must be replaced with the external key of the destination Data Extension. And action url needs to be adjusted according to the stack you are on. This example shows the url for stack 1. If you are on e.g. Stack 7 - the url will be: http://cl.s7.exct.net/DEManager.aspx

You can use the [set user info](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_set_user_info.htm&type=5) call to assign your own identifier to map browsing behaviour to your contact model. You should not use Email as an identifier, but you can do this with e.g. your Subscriber Key. This will allow you to join the behaviour stored in IGO/PI data extensions with rest of the user data.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">       
   _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);     
   _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID"}]);     
   _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);    
   </script>
```

You can [read here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_integration_with_contact_builder.htm&type=5) about what data is stored in which data extensions.