# Marketing Cloud Tracking Code to caputure Website Visitors (Identified or Unidentified)

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

I have added tracking code as below:

```
_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": usr_Email}]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView");
```

Whenever the web form is submitted, I am capturing the email and passing it to tracking code.
This works well and I do see identified visitors in IGO_PROFILES DE. I have also added only page view tracking as well on other pages so that I can capture their subsequent visits.

1. I am able to view the count of Identified and Unidentified visitors by web pages in **Web & Mobile Analytics** Dashboard
2. I can drill down to Country level to see all identified visitor from the dashboard
3. I can see all identified visitors in IGO_PROFILES DE

Questions:
 1. While IGO_PROFILES DE only shows visitor information, where do I see which all page were visited by the identified users? (Not in the analytics dashboard but in some DE)
 2. IGO_PROFILES DE captures User Id, how to link them to the Subscriber ID?

We are not an ecommerce company neither we have web content.
I have thoght of adding Form name as an item in the _etmc.push(["trackPageView") line as `_etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "item" : "MyWebForm"}]);` so that it caputres the detials in IGO_VIEWS DE but that is usually used for products and catalogs so not very much sure if this should be the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to populate details about the pages visited, without having a catalogue in place. In your case, since it is not an e-commerce scenario, I would simply create a "mock" content catalogue, and use [streaming updates](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_ctc_streaming_updates.htm) from JS to keep it updated. The Item ID passed in `trackPageView` call should correspond to the ID in your catalogue. Hence it is important to execute the `updateItem` call before pushing the `trackPageView`.

Once you have your catalogue in place, you should be seeing the PI_CONTENTVIEWS and PI_CONTENTATTRIBS data extensions becoming populated.

I will advise you to familiarise yourself with other Q/As on this topic, which might be useful for better understanding of the Web & Mobile Analytics data capture:

[Question about Collect Tracking Code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293681/question-about-collect-tracking-code)

[Collect tracking code is not working properly](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284509/collect-tracking-code-is-not-working-properly)

[How to store collect tracking data in Marketing Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271481/how-to-store-collect-tracking-data-in-marketing-cloud)

[Is possible to query data from track views?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263691/is-possible-to-query-data-from-track-views)

[Web collect code not working properly](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256143/web-collect-code-not-working-properly)

[Collect codes for non-retail scenario](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249903/collect-codes-for-non-retail-scenario)